# How do I set ACF repeater to only show X items per row

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF pro repeater fields, which renders individual images per row. However it shows all images until it wraps to the next line:

```
<div class="client-logo-web-wrapper"><?php $logo_images = get_field( 'logo' ); ?>
<?php if ( $logo_images ) :  ?>
    <?php foreach ( $logo_images as $logo_image ): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $logo_image['url']; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $logo_image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $logo_image['alt']; ?>" />
        </a>
    <p><?php echo $logo_image['caption']; ?></p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( have_rows( 'logo_gallery' ) ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_rows( 'logo_gallery' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
    <?php $client_logo = get_sub_field( 'client_logo' ); ?>
        <?php if ( $client_logo ) { ?>
            <div class="client-logo"><img src="<?php echo $client_logo['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $client_logo['alt']; ?>" />
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?></div>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php // no rows found ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Instead I would like to display a set number of images (for ex. 4) per row. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the limit, and the break the loop once you reach that limit. Also, you can also set the max number of items in your ACF field definition.

Try the following with the limit set:

```
<?php
$show = 4;
$count = 0;
?>
<?php if ( $logo_images ) :  ?>
    <?php foreach ( $logo_images as $logo_image ): ?>
<?php $count++; ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $logo_image['url']; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $logo_image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $logo_image['alt']; ?>" />
        </a>
    <p><?php echo $logo_image['caption']; ?></p>
<?php if ($count > $show) { break; } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```